# How to implement a spiral iteration in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Following is the algorithm for arranging circles in a spiral fashion.

Following clockwise direction.

[image]

following is the pseudocode (overall).

```
        let dir = [1, 0]

        function checkIntersect(c0, c1) {
            const {x0, y0, r0} = c0
            const {x1, y1, r1} = c1
           return Math.hypot(x0-x1, y0-y1) <= (r0 + r1);
        }
        
        for (let i = 0; i < circleCount; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < circleCount; j++) {
                if (checkIntersect(circles[i], circles[j])) {
incrementLocation(circles[j])
                    flip(dir)
                }
            }
        }
```

this is what I came up with for spiralling, but it's not working!!

```
    const spiralRadii = 3;

    for (let i = 1; i <= radius; i++) {
      let x = 0;
      let y = 0;
      for (let j = 0; j <= 2 * i; j++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
          if (j <= i) {
            x--;
            console.log(x, y);
          } else {
            y++;
            console.log(x, y);
          }
        } else {
          if (j <= i) {
            x++;
            console.log(x, y);
          } else {
            y--;
            console.log(x, y);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

In this manner how can I fill up the whole space with circles with address in a clock wise spiral fashion?

[image]

**Always follow Clockwise direction && during each iteration check if clockwise direction is occupied, if not move everything else to that position (while keeping the current one at the previous position),
if occupied move forward**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spiral+[js]+array

Comment: What is the final question you want to answer? I suggest you try to answer that without actually generating the spiral pattern directly.