# How to generate number pairs in spiral pattern in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to generate number pairs in spiral pattern in javascript?

expected output:

```
[0,0] [1,0] [1,-1] [0,-1] [-1,-1] [-1,0] [-1,1] [0,1] [1,1] [2,1].....
```

So the traversal will be like this:

```
[-2,1] [-1, 1]→ [0,1]→     [1,1]→    [2,1] 
         ↑                             ↓
[-2,0]   [-1,0]  [0,0] →   [1,0]    [2,0]
         ↑                   ↓         ↓
[-2,-1] [-1,-1] ← [0,-1] ← [1,-1]   [2,-1]
                                       ↓
    ...
```

this is what I came up with

```
    const radius = 3;

    for (let i = 1; i <= radius; i++) {
      let x = 0;
      let y = 0;
      for (let j = 0; j <= 2 * i; j++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
          if (j <= i) {
            x--;
            console.log(x, y);
          } else {
            y++;
            console.log(x, y);
          }
        } else {
          if (j <= i) {
            x++;
            console.log(x, y);
          } else {
            y--;
            console.log(x, y);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Without generating any matrix initially**

Number pairs should be generated as we move along...

Note that the above example it starts at `[0,0]` in reality this starting point can be any arbitrary point `[i,j]`

**We can fix a limit if we want**

Comment: Are you solving an Advent of Code problem or doing some other coding challenge? For an "infinite" map like this, you generally don't want to actually generate the spiral pattern in memory. Instead, you need to find a way to solve the problem without doing so.

Comment: No not an infinite map we can fix a limit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64325505/how-to-implement-a-spiral-iteration-in-javascript

Comment: still, my point holds. You probably want to find another way to solve the problem rather than generating this spiral in an array in memory.

Comment: Also, don't post the same question twice, please. I'm closing this as a duplicate of your other question.

Comment: No please. don't; this is a different one.

Comment: @mex It's only been two hours since you posted your original question. Have patience young grasshopper. This duplicate will be closed and deleted shortly.

Comment: I didn't got any help... that is' why !!

Comment: @mex It's only been two hours!

Comment: First thing: You can create an object with keys that hold the `i` and `j` indexes.
Say `i` is `10` and `j` is `-7`, key would be: `10,-7`, and to extract `i` and `j` from `key`: `[i,j]=key.split(",").map(k=>+k)`.
I have an algorithm for "tier" filling - I'd have to think about a "spiral" one.

Comment: Are you able to do this basic matrix spiral to begin with? That would be a good start, do a spiral that is 3*3 with a counter from 1. Get that pattern down, and it should get you on track. This codepen may assist: https://codepen.io/mitchell-boland/pen/rqdWPO?editors=1010

Comment: Can we do this starting from inwards.. starting from an arbitrary point in the centre?

Comment: Can you show it as a snippet?? please.

Comment: Starting with `i` and `j`, set `x=i+1; y=j; tier=1;`, then there are five phases:
down until `y==j-tier`, then
left until `x==i-tier`, then
up until `y==j+tier`, then
right until `x==i+tier`, then
down until `y==j+1` then: set `tier++; x++; y=j` , and repeat the five phases.
* changed so not to re-visit points.
* this way, given a point, you can deduce the tier and the phase.

Comment: Please [edit your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64325505/edit) instead of re-posting it. If this is really different, please [edit] to explain how it is different. Also, if you've been hooked up to this problem for hours, surely you've tried some approaches. Please show us your attempts - without the code to improve, we cannot help you, and we won't solve the problem for you from scratch.

Comment: I'd also add the value for each key a property that holds the index of that key in the spiral.
Say: `index:0` for the center, `1` for the next one (to the left), `2` for the next one (down from the last), etc.

Comment: Object does not ensure order of properties.
It could be stored as such: `obj={
  "0,-1": {
    index:3
  },
  "0,0": {
    index:0
  },
  "1,-1": {
    index:2
  },
  "1,0": {
    index:1
  }
}`.
So, to get an Array of the points in spiral index order, use:
`spArr=Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b)=>a[1].index-b[1].index);`.
Which will be:
`[
  [
    "0,0",
    {
      "index": 0
    }
  ],
  [
    "1,0",
    {
      "index": 1
    }
  ],
  [
    "1,-1",
    {
      "index": 2
    }
  ],
  [
    "0,-1",
    {
      "index": 3
    }
  ]
]`

Comment: You could either get `next`, or "find" all, but don't forget to limit (you don't want an infinite loop): either by `maxTier` or `maxCount`.
All of this and everything else I've wrote should get you started (if not all the way to "done").
So, "get started", and show your progress.
I'll help on the way, if needed.